# Problema de manutenção com consulta JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Tenho os seguintes pacotes e classes.

Quando vou fazer essa consulta JPA, preciso passar todo o  *full qualified name* da Classe (como está no exemplo) porque o JPA não consegue encontrá-la se eu passar somente o nome dela, nem importando a classe, funciona.

Existe alguma forma de resolver esse problema? Porque tenho que migrar alguns pacotes aqui no projeto e irá quebrar umas 20 consultas e teria que ir em cada classe e alterar manualmente.

```
br.com.projeto.dao.VendaDAO
br.com.projeto.model.Venda
br.com.projeto.model.VendaTotal

class VendaDao{

    public List<VendaTotal> getTotaisDeVentas(){
        String jpql = 
            "select new br.com.projeto.model.VendaTotal(sum v.valor) " +
            "from Venda v " +
            "group by v.data";
        return entityManager.createQuery(jpql, VentaTotal.class).getResultList();
    }

}

class Venda{
    private Double valor;
    private Date data;

    // getters e setters

}

class VendaTotal{
    private Double valor;

    public VentaTotal(Double valor){
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    // getters e setters

}
```

Comment: Tem certeza que precisa passar o full qualified name? Já tentou sem? Pq na chamada do método vc fala qual é a classe: `createQuery(jpql, VentaTotal.class)`

Comment: @IgorVenturelli sim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `getName()` da classe `VendaTotal` nas suas consultas, assim fica mais fácil de refatorar. O `String.format()` ou o `StringBuilder` também podem te ajudar a construir essa consulta.

```
String jpql = "select %s(sum(v.valor)) from Venda v group by v.data";
jpql = String.format(jpql,"new ".concat(VendaTotal.getClass().getName()));
```

Ou

```
String jpql = "select new %s(sum(v.valor)) from Venda v group by v.data";
jpql = String.format(jpql, VendaTotal.getClass().getName());
```

Com `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("select ");
        .append("new ")
        .append(VendaTotal.getClass().getName())
        .append("(sum(v.valor)) ")
        .append("from Venda v group by v.data");
String jpql = builder.toString();
```

Comment: tks brah!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta dessa forma:

```
String jpql = "select sum(v.valor) from Venda v group by v.data";
```

Com o resultado, você seta o valor total.

Comment: Ai é praticamente usar jdbc.